# multiple result Rows in one row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this kind of result from a Select like this

```
Select a.Header1, a.Header2, a.Header3, b.header4,
From a
Join b on a.id = b.id
```

give this result

```
Head1   Head2   Head3   Head4
1         A       1       AA
1         A       1       BB
1         A       1       CC
1         A       2       AA
1         A       2       CC
1         A       2       DD
1         A       2       EE
```

Is it possible to have

```
Head1   Head2   Head3   Head4 
1         A       1       AA    BB    CC
1         A       2       AA          CC    DD    EE
```

Head4 being split in different columns

Comment: Assuming you don't need extra columns, but you just want to list the data out in the 4th column, you can use `listagg`.  If not, you'll want to look into `pivoting`.

Comment: what version of oracle?  may have to use `wm_concat` instead of listagg if before 10.

Comment: I would like different columns. looking for pivoting then

Comment: in pivoting you have to have a defined list of allowed values... so could there be more than AA, BB, CC,DD,EE if so, then you're looking at dynamic SQL and pivots. and in your example BB went with CC... how would you know that was the right order? and not BB w/ EE and EE with DD?

Comment: Edited my example, BB can be null if not found. I have a list of allowed values too

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly. You can use the [`listagg()`](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=515) function to concatenate the values into a single column which you can then split after the fact. Example:

```
SELECT
    a.Header1,
    a.Header2,
    a.Header3,
    listagg(b.Header4, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY b.Header4) AS Header4
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY
    a.Header1,
    a.Header2,
    a.Header3
```

Would yield:

```
Header1   Header2   Header3   Header4 
1         A         1         AA, BB, CC
1         A         2         AA, CC, DD, EE
```